# Snowflake custom role not able to create tables on a schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-roles

1. I have a custom role (`readwrite`) which is granted to the built-in `SYSADMIN` role.
2. I have a database `CDP_MODELS` which has a schema `MODELS` in it (the owner for which is `SYSADMIN`).
3. I have a user `WCOX` who is a part of the `readwrite` role.

[image]

I need to provide the user `WCOX` write access to the `CDP_MODELS.MODELS` DB so that the user can create new tables.

What I have tried so far -

I see that the `readwrite` role has usage permission on the database as well as the schema.

[image]

But when I login as the `readwrite` role and try to create a table on the `MODELS` schema in the `CDP_MODELS` DB, it gives the following error -

> SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema
> 'MODELS'

[image]

I have also explicitly tried to run the below queries and then try creating the table, but to no luck.

```
grant usage on database CDP_MODELS to role READWRITE;
grant usage on schema CDP_MODELS.MODELS to role READWRITE;
grant select,insert on future tables in schema CDP_MODELS.MODELS to role READWRITE;
```

Is there something which I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing Create Table privilege on the Schema.

```
grant create table on schema CDP_MODELS.MODELS to role READWRITE;
```